# Cannot destructure import from node_modules, but can from file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I find a weird behaviour when writing my vite program,

```
import { Store } from '@decky.fx/react-native-essentials/lib/index';
```

the code above is working fine, but if i change it into

```
import { Store } from '@decky.fx/react-native-essentials';
```

Store will yield undefined

I have to load all modules like this

```
import All from '@decky.fx/react-native-essentials';
All.Store // this is working
```

package json for the modules are like this

```
...
"main": "lib/index.js",
"types": "lib/index.d.ts",
...
```

any ideas why it behave like this?
the repository is at `https://github.com/deckyfx/react-native-essentials/example`

Should be able to destructure modules like how react library does
`react, {useState} from "react"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey not sure but i think its happenig because  `import { Store } from '@decky.fx/react-native-essentials'` is looking for `store` in the `react-native-essentials` but its not in that file its in the sub-folder of it  `react-native-essentials/lib/index` not in the root  and so that's why you not able to destructure it from the `react-native-essentials` and as for  why this is working `import All from '@decky.fx/react-native-essentials';` its because you importing everything from the file even its subfiles/folders .

And in this case `react, {useState} from "react"` react have everything in the "react" file so that's why this works `import{useSatte} from  react`